# What is the benefits of external names for swift function?

Tags: swift, function

I kind of knowing what is a external names in a function. But I cannot give out a precise, clear and convincing answer for the question: What is the purpose of of the external names, when to use it and what is the benefits of using it.

```
func RandomInt(minimum min: Int, maximum max: Int) -> Int {
    if max < min { return min }
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((max - min) + 1))) + min
}
```

**My understanding** 
In the code above, `minimum` and `maximum` are the external names. They are "binding" to the internal names (`min` and `max`). When you calling the function, the external names should write into the argument list. This long and descriptive external name improves code readability when you using the function.

Please correct my understandings if anything is wrong or add more if needed

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The external parameters were needed mainly for compatibility with Obj-C methods because Obj-C is using them too (although they are named differently), however they are also helping readability in method caller context.

Note that external parameters are actually a part of the method name therefore you can overload methods by changing the external parameter.

Another interesting point of named parameters is the ability to provide default values:

```
func test(x: Int = 0, y: Int = 1, z: Int = 2) {
    print("x: \(x), y: \(y), z: \(z)")
}

// we can skip a parameter in the middle!
test(x: 10, z: 5)
```

By the way, named parameters are common in many programming languages (see a list on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter)). Every language implements them slightly differently though.

Comment: so because of the the Obj-C has the external names, the swift also added that for compatibility with Obj-C. This might be a bad question: I've learned that the idea of creating Swift is to using it to change the Obj-C. If so why swift has to take care the Obj-C compatibility?

Comment: @SLN A language is the minor thing. On a platform the important thing are all the frameworks (Foundation, UIKit etc.). And they are all written in Obj-C. If Apple was to come with a new language, all those frameworks had to be compatible with Swift, therefore the interoperability between Obj-C and Swift was very important.

Comment: hmmmm... very convincing explanation! Thanks a lot for your help ")

Answer (score 6):

According to the [swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html),

> The use of external parameter names can allow a function to be called
>   in an expressive, sentence-like manner, while still providing a
>   function body that is readable and clear in intent.

for example,

```
func sayHello(to person: String, and anotherPerson: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(person) and \(anotherPerson)!"
}

print(sayHello(to: "Bill", and: "Ted"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the vivid example and explanation. It do improves a lot of readability of the coded and makes it more close to nature language.